# ReflectionException error on php artisan routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Everytime I run `php artisan routes`, I get `ReflectionException` error and that `UsersController` class does not exist. I'm pretty sure it does.

I tried `php composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan clear-compiled`, they all give the same error.

This is my error log in `/app/storage/logs/`

```
[2014-03-30 01:41:24] production.ERROR: exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class UsersController does not exist' in C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector.php:28
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector.php(28): ReflectionClass->__construct('UsersController')
#1 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(269): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector->getRoutable('UsersController', 'users')
#2 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php(211): Illuminate\Routing\Router->controller('users', 'UsersController')
#3 C:\wamp\www\re3\app\routes.php(14): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('controller', Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\re3\app\routes.php(14): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::controller('users', 'UsersController')
#5 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\start.php(269): require('C:\wamp\www\re3...')
#6 [internal function]: {closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#7 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(792): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#8 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(569): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->fireAppCallbacks(Array)
#9 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(552): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootApplication()
#10 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(44): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#11 C:\wamp\www\re3\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(33): Illuminate\Console\Application::make(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#12 C:\wamp\www\re3\artisan(46): Illuminate\Console\Application::start(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#13 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Do you have a callstack to share? I'm afraid that just the name of the exception class is not enough, not eve to guess, what may be happening.

Comment: You mean the names of the methods in my controllers?

Comment: When you get an error, usually you also get a callstack of the error, check your log if you don't get it in the command line. This callstack may gives us some light on what's causing the error.

Comment: I have updated my question with the results from `app/storage/logs/` I hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Somehow Laravel is not being able to find your UsersController, run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Then check the file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`, your UsersController has to be there, otherwise composer won't be able to autoload it and Laravel will not have access to it.

if you cannot find your controllers in int, you have to check:

1) Your composer.json file, the folder where your controllers are must be in:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/controllers",
                  ....
    ],
```

2) Check if your classes are correctly named.

3) If you are using a namespace:

class UsersController extends Controller { ... }

You must use the namespace in your references to it and, probably it would be better, in this case, to use PSR-4 (or even PSR-0) to autoload your classes.

4) Compare classes that you have in autoload_classmap.php with those that are not there. There must be a difference in naming or directory placement.

5) Check if your classes all start with

```
<?php
```

and not just

```
<?
```

This may not make too much difference for composer nor PHP, but it does for Laravel.

Comment: I commented out `Routes::controller('users')` and I got the same error but this time `Class ListingsController` not found.
I checked `autoload_classmap.php` and I could not find `UsersController` nor `ListingsController`

Comment: Added some more info to try to help you figure it.

Comment: #5 was the solution. I can't believe such a small detail can make all the difference. My classes were using `<?` instead of `<?php`.

Thank you very much

Comment: Nice! I almost not added that last one. :)

Comment: `composer dumpautoload` worked a charm! Looking everywhere for this solution. Thankyou.

Comment: I was able to fix it by entering Fully Qualified namespace in my routes.php file. None of the above solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Same Issue happend with me. I just forgot to put request library into controller header. just put below line to your controller's use statement.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

this is work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller file check the namespace.

For example,

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\home;
```

In the name space above the controller file should exist in the home folder. If it exists in the home folder and if I have not included home above it give an reflection error.

Simply put the name space should correspond the folder structure where the controller file is placed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happens that I had two controllers with the same name but in different locations:

> app\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController.php

and

> app\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\PasswordController.php

The last one

> app\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\PasswordController.php

had a wrong namespace (*namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;* instead of **namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;*) and because of this I constantly get the *ReflectionException* exception